# Bahamas Visa Enquiry

Tags: visas

I’m planning a trip to the Bahamas from Nigeria. Most of the flights transit between the US/Germany.  Do I have to apply for a transit visa before the Bahamas application or it’s the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the bahamas Visa first and then only you can apply for Transit Visa.

For US and germany, you definetly need a transit visa.

Comment: Ok. Says I might not require a transit visa if transit is under 12 hours and I wouldn’t have to leave the transit area

Comment: Yes. I would suggest to take flights that doesn't require a transit visa. US Transit visas may not be easy to get.

Comment: Hard to find a flight without a transit.

Comment: OP is a Nigerian national and, as such, would require an [airport transit visa (ATV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Airport_transit) when transiting through any airport in the Schengen area. The site you have linked to is not affiliated with German Government (or any other official info). There is a [comprehensive answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/) regarding Schengen transit.

Comment: Corrected the answer

Comment: @Giorgio We don't know the asker's nationality. They just say that they're travelling from Nigeria. (So they're _probably_ Nigerian but the answer's claim "you definitely need a transit visa" can't be stated with that much certainty.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby agreed; I should have said *if* but it was more about pointing to the TSE Q&A and that the link in the response was not definitive. In truth, the answer should be, first get a visa for the Bahamas, then apply for the visa(s) appropriate to the country/countries of transit.